# Finding presentations of (finite) metacyclic groups: Doubts about one of D. L. Johnson's books.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am reading the book *"Presentations of Groups"*, by D.L Johnson and I have doubts about page 88, Proposition 1.

> Why is there a need to prove that $N \cong \mathbb{Z}_m$?

Because it's given that $N=\langle x\rangle$ and it's also given that $x^m=e$.

Please refer to the book.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't looked at the book, but $N=\langle x \rangle$ with $x^m=e$ does not immediately imply that $x$ has order $m$.

Comment: They had proved that $C$ is a factor group of $G$ but how that determines $|N|=m$

Comment: I think [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RYeIcopMH-IC&lpg=PA88&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q&f=false) is the part of the book referred to.